# if condition for a buttons center

Tags: ios, cgpoint

I want to make an if statement that says when a buttons center is at a certain position then something will happen.  I've tried

```
if (button.center == CGPointMake (x,y){
    statement
}
```

but no go  how do i do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `CGPointEqualToPoint`:

```
if (CGPointEqualToPoint(button.center, CGPointMake (x,y))) {
    statement
}
```

Be aware that this is defined as follows and performs an **exact** floating point comparison:

```
CG_INLINE bool
__CGPointEqualToPoint(CGPoint point1, CGPoint point2)
{
  return point1.x == point2.x && point1.y == point2.y;
}
#define CGPointEqualToPoint __CGPointEqualToPoint
```

If you want to build in a tolerance, you could define a function as follows:

```
CG_INLINE bool
__CGPointNearToPoint(CGPoint point1, CGPoint point2, CGFloat maxAcceptableDistance)
{
    return sqrtf(powf(point2.x - point1.x, 2) + powf(point2.y - point1.y, 2)) < maxAcceptableDistance;
}
#define CGPointNearToPoint __CGPointNearToPoint
```

Comment: I'm trying to invalidate a timer after 5 seconds so I have a button start out at one position then animate to another place. Then I use the suggested if statement above to stop the timer when the button reaches the final destination after 5 seconds. But the timer is invalidated almost immediately. How can I do this.

Comment: You should post that as a separate question, as it has to do with how UIKit animation works.  If you look at the animation methods on `UIView`, there is one with a completion block.

Comment: I used animation completed block and it worked just the way I needed it to. Thanks Brian. I will mark this as answered as your first comment was right for what I asked